# How to create customised form validation with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here is the code I've created for validating my form.

```
$(function () {
    $('#subbtn').click(function () {
        if ($('#course').val('x')) {
            $('#s1').show();
        }
        if ($('#sem').val('x')) {
            $('#s2').show();
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<button id="subbtn" type="submit>Submit</button
<span id="$s1" style="display:none;">*</span>
<span id="$s2" style="display:none;">*</span>
```

`#course` and `#sem` are the ids of List boxes.
After leaving both blank and press button it works properly (both the star will display), but after selecting first listbox and leave the second one empty, and prss the button then it  gives the same result (that is, shows the both stars instead of one)
Please help, Thank you in advance

Comment: How does the form is being generated? Dynamically?

Comment: check my updated code: in html id whats the use of $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#subbtn', function () {
        if ($('#course').val() == '') {
            $('#s1').show();
        } else {
            $('#s1').hide();
  }
        if ($('#sem').val() == '') {
            $('#s2').show();
        } else {
            $('#s2').hide();
  }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="course">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="be">B.E</option>
 <option value="mba">MBA</option>
 <option value="arts">Arts</option>
 <option value="finance">Finance</option>
</select>
<select id="sem">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="1">1St</option>
 <option value="2">2nd</option>
 <option value="3">3rd</option>
 <option value="4">4th</option>
</select>
<button id="subbtn" type="submit">Submit</button>
<span id="s1" style="display:none;">*</span>
<span id="s2" style="display:none;">*</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The condition is incorrect, it should be

```
if ($('#course').val() == 'x') {...}
```

instead of

```
if($('#course').val('x')) {...}
```

The same for the second list, `#sem`.

Comment: Thank you.  I've modified, but first time it works, but second time after selecting the first listbox, its not working.